# GGPLOT with lines for factor on x-axis data not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code which I am attempting to run to plot monthly counts against the month, for 4 different years to see trends in seasonal periods.

```
g <- ggplot(groups.byYearAndMonth,aes(y=number, x=month.Raised, group=year.Raised))
g <- geom_line()
```

I keep getting an error in the console stating:

> Error in geom_point() + geom_line() :    non-numeric argument to
>   binary operator

The data has layout and format:

```
year.Raised  month.Raised  number
       2016           Nov       6
```

with the year as a numeric variable and the month and number as factors.

Comment: Please read [(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how do I ask a good question, [(2)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) How to create a MCVE as well as [(3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R. Then edit and improve your question accordingly. I.e., abstract from your real problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line should be `g<-g + geom_line()`.